# How to Add Listeners to RadioButtons in EXTJS4

Tags: listener, extjs4, radio-group

I'm very new to ExtJs and I wanted to display an alert box on clicking one of the radio buttons, but it does not seem to work. Could anyone guide me through this step? The listener does not seem to work.

```js
{
    xtype: 'radiogroup',
    fieldLabel: 'Does Nodes have DHCP IP Scheme?',
    id:'dhcpRadio',
    columns: [50, 50],
    // Arrange radio buttons into two columns, distributed vertically
    columns: 2,
    vertical: true,
    items: [{
    boxLabel: 'Yes',
        name: 'rb', 
        inputValue: 'yes',
        listeners: {
            check: function(rb,value){
                if(value=='yes') 
                    alert('yes');
                else alert('no');
            }
        }
    },{
        boxLabel: 'No',
        name: 'rb',
        inputValue: 'no',
        checked: true
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like Gregory just said, Radio does not have a `click` event.
You could try the `change` event instead:

```js
listeners: {
    change : function(rb, newValue, oldValue, options) {
        if( newValue === 'yes') {
            alert('Yes')
        } else {
            alert('No')
        }
    }
}
```

See the [API documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Radio) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Radio  do not have a click event

Instead of the listeners try this:

```
handler: function(ctl, val) {
  alert("ddd");
}
```